# How do you setInterval while looping through dates?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of dates I want to loop through, but want to wait a certain amount of time at the end of each date. I can't figure out how to do this with setInterval. Here's my code:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 1, 1);
var i = setInterval(function(){
    // do something

    date++;
    if(date === new Date(2014, 6, 19)) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 200);
```

My array is as such:

```
[new Date(2014, 6, 18), 'US', 1500],
[new Date(2014, 6, 18), 'CA', 1000],
[new Date(2014, 6, 19), 'US', 1800],
[new Date(2014, 6, 19), 'CA', 1200],
[new Date(2014, 6, 20), 'US', 2000],
[new Date(2014, 6, 20), 'CA', 1500],
```

...etc...

How do I do this?

Comment: What is `date++` supposed to do?  Add a day?

Comment: date === new Date will always be false no matter what

Comment: Yes, I'd like to add a day. How would I do that?

Comment: You say you have "an array of dates", but you don't include this array in your code above.

Comment: @Coby - I don't think he meant array of dates, I think he meant sequence of dates.

Comment: My array looks like this
[new Date(2014, 6, 18), 'US', 1534],
[new Date(2014, 6, 18), 'CA', 1534],
[new Date(2014, 6, 19), 'GT', 1534],
[new Date(2014, 6, 19), 'CA', 32063],

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I added the array to my original question. Is there anything else that is unclear? I am simply trying to loop through the dates in the array and wait a certain amount of time before the loop begins again.

Comment: @user1748712 yes this is totally unclear.  Please post the code for this loop.  I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: no, comparing a number to an object using "===" will always be false. the only way it could be true is by comparing the new object to the same new object, but since it doesn't exist yet, that can't happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To "increment by one day" do this:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
```

This will auto-magically roll to the next month.

cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Also as @JonathanLonowski says in the comments (indirectly) make this change:

```
if(date == new Date(2014, 6, 19)) {
```

or

```
if(date.getTime() === (new Date(2014, 6, 19)).getTime()) {
```

Then you should be GTG

Comment: @user1748712 Why not?

Comment: @Hogan This fixes one issue, but leaves `===` as a problem. 2 different objects, including `Date`s, cannot be equal regardless of any values they may hold or represent.

Comment: Using `>=` should compare them by their values, and account for any possible differences in the hours, etc.

Comment: if you are trying to compare the day, month, and year, compare those three values. Otherwise you will also end up comparing times since casting a date to a number will convert it to a timestamp.